# How to ignore @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I have a pojo, and most of the time I don't want to write a field to Json, but for a specific contition I want to write this value to json.  For example my model is;

```
public class Person {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public String value;
}
```

Is it possible to configure Object Mapper to ignore `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new ObjectMapper and disable MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper = objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
Person person = objectMapper.convertValue(personJson, Person.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I do not know of a quite direct way to really let the `ObjectMapper` ignore a particular annotation but why not using `@JsonView`s?

Just define some views…

```
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }
    public static class Internal {
    }
}
```

…put it on your conditional field…

```
public class Person {
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public String value;
}
```

…and serialize it with your mapper…

```
    String result = mapper
      .writerWithView(Views.Public.class)
      .writeValueAsString(person);
```

The samples above were taken from [good old Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation#serialize-using-json-views) where you can find even more nice variants of this solution.

Comment: I didn't know about JsonView. I will try and let you know whether it worked or not. Thanks for advice